# Creating a Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I recorded a macro to reference data on Sheet1 and pull it over to Sheet2.

I need to continue until there is no more data present on Sheet1(or Row 209).

```
Sub Macro1()
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet1!RC"
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet1!R[-1]C"
    Range("A3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet1!R[-2]C"
    Range("A4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet1!R[-2]C"
    Range("A5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet1!R[-3]C"
    Range("A6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet1!R[-4]C"
    Range("A7").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the pattern always the same every six cells? In your example, cells A1 to A3 are always the same (i.e. cell A1 on Sheet1) and A4 to A6 are the same (i.e. cell A2 on Sheet1). Showing a snapshot of your data may help here...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like from your code that you are simply copying and pasting from Sheet1 to Sheet2, but for each row you go down in Sheet2, you go up a row in Sheet1. In other words, `"=Sheet1!R[-x]C"` makes it look like you are going up a row by x.

What your code is showing is a step-by-step process of selecting each cell, then changing it. Why not do this all at once [without the .Select statments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/2658159)?

For example, a `For...Next` loop could do this:

```
For i = 1 To 209
  Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(210 - i, 1).Value = _
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
Next
```

This copies the contents of the cells (the .Value property) directly.